# Statistics: Exponential Distribution given 2 probabilities

Tags: statistics

Given:

$P(X > 5 ) = .7$

$P(X > 15) = .343$

Find:

$P(X < 2.5) =  ?$

To start this off, I was thinking about using the complement to find $P(X \ge 2.5)$, but I'm not sure. Alternatively, I was thinking about using $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}(1/\mu)e^{-t/\mu}$, but I don't know how to start

Comment: Are you sure it's $P(X>15)$ and not $P(X>1.5)$ ?

Comment: @Herman Yes sir, this question is a continuation of previous steps. So it is $P(X > 15)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We know that $$S_X(x) = \Pr[X > x] = e^{-\lambda x},$$ where $\lambda$ is the rate parameter.  Consequently, we have $$S_X(5) = e^{-5\lambda} = 0.7, \\ S_X(15) = e^{-15\lambda} = 0.343.$$  Either one of these leads to the same solution for $\lambda$, namely $$\lambda = \frac{\log \frac{10}{7}}{5} = \frac{\log \frac{1000}{343}}{15}.$$  This is because $\frac{1000}{343} = \left(\frac{10}{7}\right)^3$.  So one of the two conditions is redundant.

We also know that $$F_X(x) = \Pr[X \le x] = 1 - e^{-\lambda x},$$ so all that remains is to compute $$F_X(2.5) = 1 - e^{-2.5 \lambda},$$ which I leave as an exercise.

Of course, we could shortcut the entire process, knowing that $2.5 = \frac{5}{2}$, thus $$e^{-2.5 \lambda} = \left(e^{-5\lambda}\right)^{1/2} = \sqrt{0.7}.$$

Comment: This is not correct because you forgot to subtract from $1$ at the end.  You have $P(X \lt 2.5)=0.8367$ and $P(X \gt 5)=0.7$ which sum to more than $1$

Comment: @RossMillikan My answer is completely correct:  Note I wrote "all that remains is to compute $F_X(2.5) = 1 - e^{-2.5 \lambda}$."  Then at the end, I write $e^{-2.5 \lambda} = \sqrt{0.7}$.  It might look like I'm suggesting the answer is $\sqrt{0.7}$, but one simply needs to pay attention at what I am saying.

Answer (score 0):

The exponential distribution has only one parameter, so we only need one data point to evaluate it.  We have $P(X \gt t)=1-e^{-\lambda t}$.  If we accept the first point, we just write
$$P(X \gt 5)=0.7\\
e^{-5\lambda}=0.7\\
-5\lambda=\log(0.7)\\
\lambda=0.7133$$
We can then plug this into the distribution to get
$$P(X \lt 2.5)=1-e^{-0.7133\cdot 2.5}\\
P(X \lt 2.5)=0.1633$$
Because the time from the second point is three times the time from the first and $0.7^3=0.343$ the two data points are consistent.