# Statistics: Finding mean lifetime with given lifetimes

Tags: statistics

Given:

$P(X>5) = .7$

$P(X>15) = .343$

$P(X < 2.5) = .8367$

Find the mean lifetime.

I tried finding $\mu = 1/\lambda$, but that wasn't the correct answer. I'm not sure what equation to use in order to find the mean given the three

Comment: [facepalm]  Go back and **carefully** reread the answer I posted to your previous question:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3411375/statistics-exponential-distribution-given-2-probabilities/3411450#3411450  The answer to your current question is already provided in my previous answer.  That this has somehow escaped your attention suggests to me that you are being careless, or don't understand basic concepts of probability.

Answer (score 0):

The question cannot be answered.  $P(X \gt 15 \vee X \lt 2.5) \gt 1$, so this is not a probability distribution.  Even if that is fixed, if you only have $P(X \gt 15)$ is some number there could be a small part of the distribution with $X$ *huge* that pulls the expected value up.  You need to be given that the distribution is of some form that lets you use the data to get the parameters.  It sounds like you are assuming a geometric distribution, but you did not say it was.

Comment: Weird. I should've mentioned that this is exponentially distributed, with X = the number of years representing the lifetime of a transistor. My bad

Comment: That doesn't change the fact that the data is inconsistent.